# How to set multiple nested levels in a permanova in R?

Tags: r, permutation, vegan

I need help coding a nested permanova analises in R. I have a matrix os distances that I want to partition the variance between 3 nested levels.  I'm using the adonis function, and from what I understood I also want to repeat the nested structure within the strata parameter so the random shuffling is restricted within levels. It is the first time I'm using such approach, and I think I'm missing something. Is it possible to set multiple nested levels in the strata parameter? So far, I was able to perform up to this point, but I'm not sure is the right direction.
When I try to set nested levels within strata, I get the following error:

```
perm = adonis(lma.dist ~ Family/genus/Spec, strata= Family/genus/Spec, data=df)

> Error in getPermuteMatrix(permutations, n, strata = strata):
object 'Family' not found
```

But when I set only one level on strata (or even with no level), adonis function seems to run fine.(run with all dataset)

```
perm2 = adonis(lma.dist ~ Family/genus/Spec, strata= df$Spec, data=df)

Call:
adonis(formula = lma.dist ~ Family/genus/Spec, data = df, strata = df$Family) 
Blocks:  strata 
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

                   Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)    
Family             13   110.262  8.4817 20.5826 0.47732  0.001 ***
Family:genus       12    34.755  2.8963  7.0284 0.15046  0.001 ***
Family:genus:Spec   5     3.155  0.6309  1.5311 0.01366  0.056 .  
Residuals         201    82.828  0.4121         0.35856           
Total             231   231.000                 1.00000           
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

lma.dist is a matrix object (232 x 232) of euclidean distances. This is a subset:

```
dput(head(lma.dist))structure(c(0, 0.645, 0.538, 0.538, 0.108, 0.43,0.645, 0, 0.108, 0.108, 0.753, 0.215, 0.538, 0.108, 0, 0, 0.645, 0.108, 0.538, 0.108, 0, 0, 0.645, 0.108, 0.108, 0.753, 0.645, 0.645, 0, 0.538, 0.43, 0.215, 0.108, 0.108, 0.538, 0, 0.43, 0.215, 0.108, 0.108, 0.538, 0, 0, 0.645, 0.538, 0.538, 0.108, 0.43, 0.968, 0.323, 0.43, 0.43, 1.075, 0.538, 0.215, 0.86, 0.753, 0.753, 0.108, 0.645, 0.215, 0.86, 0.753, 0.753, 0.108, 0.645, 0.43, 0.215, 0.108, 0.108, 0.538, 0, 0.215, 0.86, 0.753, 0.753, 0.108, 0.645, 0.108, 0.753, 0.645, 0.645, 0, 0.538, 0.215, 0.86, 0.753, 0.753, 0.108, 0.645, 0, 0.645, 0.538, 0.538, 0.108, 0.43, 0.323, 0.968, 0.86, 0.86, 0.215, 0.753, 0.43, 0.215, 0.108, 0.108, 0.538, 0, 0.43, 1.075, 0.968, 0.968, 0.323, 0.86, 0.215, 0.86, 0.753, 0.753, 0.108, 0.645), .Dim = c(6L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(c("Xl_AP_319","Xl_AP_351", "Xl_AP_326", "Xl_AP_422", "Xl_AP_146", "Xl_AP_188"), c("Xl_AP_319", "Xl_AP_351", "Xl_AP_326", "Xl_AP_422", "Xl_AP_146", "Xl_AP_188", "Xl_AP_252", "Xl_AP_101", "Xl_AP_218", "Xl_CE_334", "Vt_Q16_304", "Vt_Q16_124", "Vt_EF_255", "Vt_EF_159", "Vt_EF_191", "Vt_EF_28", "Vt_CE_199", "Vt_CE_185", "Vt_CE_271", "Vp_Q16_297")))
```

df is a data frame (232 x 3) with labels (factors) for Family, genus and Spec. row names and colnames are the same in both data.

```
dput(head(df[1:20,]))structure(list(Family("Xyridaceae","Xyridaceae", "Xyridaceae","Xyridaceae", "Xyridaceae", "Xyridaceae"), genus =c("Xyris","Xyris", "Xyris", "Xyris", "Xyris", "Xyris"), Spec = c("Xyris longiscapa","Xyris longiscapa", "Xyris longiscapa", "Xyris longiscapa", "Xyris longiscapa", "Xyris longiscapa")), .Names = c("Family", "genus", "Spec"), row.names =("Xl_AP_319","Xl_AP_351", "Xl_AP_326", "Xl_AP_422", "Xl_AP_146", "Xl_AP_188"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How do you want samples to be shuffled here, only shuffling samples within the combinations of `Family + Genus + Spec`? You can achieve two levels of hierarchy with the functions in the *permute* pkg which *vegan* uses to generate restricted permutations. But if all you want to do is restrict shuffling to take place within so predefined levels of a factor you can imply create that factor as the interaction of two of more categorical variables and then use that as the Blocks of a permutation design that you set up using `how()`.

Comment: The error here is due to the values passed to `strata` being looked for in parent environment - i.e. we expect `strata` to be passed a factor vector. Your code is expecting `strata` to be evaluated in `data` and that is not something we allow.

Comment: If interest is in testing for variation at different levels of the hierarchy, then there are ways to do this by say testing the variance due to one level and then partialling that out and looking at the next level in the hierarchy (I forget if you work from lower levels to higher levels or from higher to lower). I have an example of this taken from Leps & Smilauer's text book and reimplemented using *vegan* and *permute*. See the crayfish example in the slides from a workshop I gave at a meeting a year ago: https://github.com/gavinsimpson/esa-advanced-vegan

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments @GavinSimpson! If I want to shuffle only within each class, how do I set the interactions of categorical variables in `blocks`? I'm sorry but I didn't quite understand how to "create that factor as the interaction of two of more categorical variables" . Also, thanks for sharing your slides, it looks a very interesting approach, I will look more into it.